# How to ignore upper directory .htaccess Options?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, options

How do I have a current directory `.htaccess` ignore `Options` from upper directory `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply specify what you want at the current level (and subseqently). If you want it all disabled just:

```
Options None
```

Or if you want to disable particular features for example:

```
Options -Index -ExecCGI
```

Or if you want to enable additional directive:

```
Options +Includes
```

If you want just one feature turned on, it's really nice and readable if you are explicit about it:

```
Options None +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: I just double checked on Apache httpd 2.2.24, works exactly as I described.

Comment: @JMoore Are you sure? Have you tried it? What problems are you experiencing?

Answer (score 3):

The [.htaccess documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#how) covers this very well, all you have to do is specify them and the later ones will override the earlier ones

> The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all subdirectories thereof. However, it is important to also remember that there may have been .htaccess files in directories higher up. Directives are applied in the order that they are found. Therefore, a .htaccess file in a particular directory may override directives found in .htaccess files found higher up in the directory tree. And those, in turn, may have overridden directives found yet higher up, or in the main server configuration file itself.